# position of like box when user clicks facebook like buttom

Tags: jquery, css, facebook, position

I have a facebook 'like & share' button on my site. I have it placed at the bottom of the page in the footer. The problem I have is that when a user clicks the like or share button, the box that opens for them to make the 'like' is positioned below the like button making it unseeable on my site as the button is on the bottom of the page.

Is there any way to make the box appear above the button?

Here's the link to my site so you can see what I mean:

http://97squared.co.uk

Heres the code I have,

JavaScript: just inside opening of 'body'

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="facebook-button">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.97squared.co.uk/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.facebook-button {
position: relative;
top: -8px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It seems everything fine to me, delete your cache and try again. Regards.

Comment: in firefox it is not fine heres a screendump http://97squared.co.uk/img/screendump.jpg